# How to install dependencies of a custom python package

Tags: python, pip, packaging

I have built a Python package according to the documentation: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Everything works, but when I call pip install my_package.whl, the dependencies are not installed.

The dependencies are listed in the pyproject.toml file as follows:
requires = ["hatchling", "package1", "package2"]

**Question 1.** During the build, I can see the following log:

```
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (hatchling, pydicom~=2.3.1)
```

What does it mean the dependencies installed and for what purpose?

**Question 2.** How to achieve the behavior, where after typing 'pip install my_package.whl', the required dependencies are installed beforehand. This must be possible, becaus all of the available python packages work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is for build time dependencies.

You want to use `dependencies` for runtime ones.

i.e.

```py
dependencies = ["package1", "package2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it in the meantime.

**Q1**: These are packages required during the build, not for using the package.

**Q2**: Use setuptool and the setup.py file instead of pyproject.toml
The content of the file is in my case:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='Description',
    author='Karol',
    packages=['my_package'],
    install_requires=[
        'numpy~=1.23.4',
        'pillow~=9.3.0',
        'pydicom~=2.3.1'
    ],
    zip_safe=False
)
```